# Ubuntu installed on hard drive does not boot "no boot device found"

Tags: boot, uefi

I can boot from USB but the Ubuntu installation on my internal hard drive does not boot. I have reinstalled Ubuntu but it's still saying `no boot device found`.

This is what I can see in Gparted from a live USB session

[image: Gparted screenshot showing ESP, 200 GB unmounted ext4 partition, 200 GB ext4 partition mounted on /media... swap and small unallocated]

Comment: What brand/model system. If Acer you need UEFI trust settings. Or may be booting in wrong mode. You show ESP for UEFI boot, is system set to boot in UEFI boot mode with Secure Boot off? And some other systems require work arounds. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: @EODCraftStaff how is this a duplicate of that? There's no evidence that it's a dual boot at all.

Comment: Read it wrong....

Comment: If Dell: http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln297060/xps-13-9343--how-to-install-ubuntu-developer-edition-1404-on-a-dell-pc-configured-for-the-unified-extensible-firmware-interface--uefi--bios?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

Go to BIOS setting and check Boot-Device Option setting, Internal HDD must be enabled there or Simply **Load Default** the BIOS setting.